# Model of spherical wave fronts in relativity

Tags: relativity, geometry

In relativity, the 3-surface formed by light rays emanating from an event as they evolve in time has the shape of a [hypercone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercone) wich is flat. I have difficulties seeing how can a spherical wave front, that has intrinsic curvature as a 2-surface can be modelled with a flat 3-surface.

In the usual 2+1 graphical simplification it is straightforward, given that 2D circles have no intrinsic curvature there is no problem modelling expanding circular wave fronts as flat conical surfaces in $R^3$.

But I can't quite get how this is done in 3+1 space with spherical wave fronts. How is the intrinsic curvature of a spherical wave front modelled with a flat 3-surface? 
On the other hand I don't think a hypercone can be isometrically embedded in a space different from $R^4$.

Answer (score 0):

A hyper cone exists in 4-dimensional Minkowski space.  You may be confusing the curved geometric properties of a Euclidean solid in flat space with the warped properties of space-time in General Relativity.

The equation of a hyper cone is:

a^2 + y^2 + z^2 - w^2 = 0

There is no adjustment for relativistic speeds or gravitational fields.  You might think of it as the 4-dimensional equivalent of a 3-dimensional shape that expands in time.  The Wikipedia article is very helpful in explaining how a hyper cone forms a sphere where it intersects a hyper plane: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercone.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact that in 3-dimensional(2+1) Minkowski space the cone surface includes the time expansion as the time axis lies inside the cone. But in the 4-dimensional case the 3-surface hypercone can be thought of independently of the time axis, and the hypercone intersected by a hyperplane indeed gives a 2-sphere surface, but unlike in the 2+1 case with the circle an instant time 3-slice of 4-dimensional Minkowski space is the hypercone flat 3-surface, rather than the 2-sphere that could model a spherical wave front.

Comment: @Walterscott:  The problem may be that it's difficult or impossible to visualize a hyper cone, if I follow you correctly.

Comment: That always adds confusion but no, that is not my point.  Do you see that an instant in time slice in Minkosky 2+1 space gives the circle wave front in a plane(since a circle can be realized in the plane, having no intrinsic curvature) , while in the 3+1 case you get the flat 3-space(hypercone), and you need to further intersect it once more to obtain the 2-sphere? In other words, the 2-sphere that models a spherical wave front and its intrinsic curvature cannot be modelled as 3-spatial slices in time.